# Skobbler Offline Maps

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'm using Skobbler for my maps project. I want to allow users to download parts of map for offline usage. As I could get from documentation, we can download maps for cities, states or countries using  `offlinePackageCode` for that area.
My question is, how to download the map for any area? Or how to get the offline package code for my searched location? E.g. I'm at coordinate A near Northwich (UK). Reverse geocoding returns a street:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.mapView coordinateForPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.mapView.frame),
                                                                            CGRectGetMidY(self.mapView.frame))];
SKSearchResult *searchObject = [[SKReverseGeocoderService sharedInstance] reverseGeocodeLocation:coord];
```

`searchObject.name` is Hemming Street, `offlinePackageCode` is empty string.

`searchObject.parentSearchResults` contains the city object Northwich, but its type is `SKSearchResultParent` which does not have property `offlinePackageCode`.

So how can I download the map for this area?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Not at all an answer to your question but: Code is calling CGRectGetMidX for both parameters -- maybe second parameter should be CGRectGetMidY?  Also, you could just use the `self.mapView.centerCoordinate` property instead of manually calculating the coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the SDK does not allow downloading maps for dynamic bounding boxes but only priorly predefined map cuts.

E.e. we cannot create on demand a map for Northwich, but knowing that such a map will be required we can create a map for Northwich in advance and add it to our maps.xml file so it can be downloaded when required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ando. It's not a good news for me but anyway, if I try to handle it by allowing download for most popular cities (i.e. the ones present in maps.xml), is there a way to get the city offline package code by reverse geocoding?

Comment: Let me look research it

Comment: Right now there are no "helper" functions for easily achieving the scenario you are describing, so you will have to implement it yourself – for each map presented in our maps.xml (or maps.json) file we also offer its bounding box – based on the current user's position you can detect what packages/bounding boxes contain that specific area (e.g. It could be a city and a country or just the country) and decide what package to start downloading

Comment: Thanks! I've already achieved what I wanted by parsing the XML and getting needed area by bounding boxes + area types.